# R Converting large character string to dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, blob, r-markdown

I am working on a project where we imported the data from Blob storage. The data is stored as one giant character string.

The columns are separated by a comma, and the rows are separated by this character "\r\"

How do I make this a dataframe?

Here is an example of the data:

```
 X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,\r\yes,yes,no,no,yes,\r\yes,yes,yes,no,yes
```

and it should look like this in a dataframe:

```
     X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
  1  yes yes no  no yes
  2  yes yes yes no yes
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have u read it in R.  Can u show the dput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one is to replace the `,\r\` with the new line character `\n`. However, you should note that in the example below, I had to use the double backslash since `\` is an escape character in R. Modify as needed in your live example, but this should work either way.

```
x = 'X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,\\r\\yes,yes,no,no,yes,\\r\\yes,yes,yes,no,yes'
x = gsub(',\\r\\', '\n', x, fixed=TRUE)

> read.csv(text=x)
   X1  X2  X3 X4  X5
1 yes yes  no no yes
2 yes yes yes no yes
```

Comment: great answer, but voting up the read.table() answer since it will help others a bit more

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` to read the single string data.  Assuming that the `\` is escaped, after reading with `sep=","`, use `sub` to replace the `\` with `""`

```
out <- read.table(text = str1, sep=",", fill = TRUE, 
 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[-6]
out$X1 <- sub("[\\]", "", out$X1)
out
#   X1  X2  X3 X4  X5
#1 yes yes  no no yes
#2 yes yes yes no yes
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,\r\\yes,yes,no,no,yes,\r\\yes,yes,yes,no,yes"
```

Comment: @brittenb Thanks, I was in the middle of changing it to specify the `header=TRUE`